# OS X - how to calculate normalized file name

Tags: macos, unicode, utf-8, unicode-normalization, hfs+

I need to create a mapping between file names generated on Windows and OS X.  I know that OS X ["converts all file names to decomposed Unicode"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1235/_index.html) however, ["most volume formats do not follow the exact specification for these normal forms"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1173/_index.html)

So, it does not seem a simple matter of converting the Windows name to NFD using a standard UTF8 API and being sure I have the correct OS X name.  Is there a way to determine what the actual OS X file name will be without actually creating the file in the file system and then scanning the directory to see what was actually created?

Answer (score 3):

I think the [answer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#UnicodeSubtleties) is this from TechNote 1150 HFS Plus Volume Format:

> Note: The Mac OS Text Encoding Converter provides several constants
> that let you convert to and from the canonical, decomposed form stored
> on HFS Plus volumes. When using CreateTextEncoding to create a text
> encoding, you should set the TextEncodingBase to
> kTextEncodingUnicodeV2_0, set the TextEncodingVariant to
> kUnicodeCanonicalDecompVariant, and set the TextEncodingFormat to
> kUnicode16BitFormat. Using these values ensures that the Unicode will
> be in the same form as on an HFS Plus volume, even as the Unicode
> standard evolves.

Comment: That's specific to HFS+, while your question appears to want a generic answer!

Comment: This changed in Mac OS X 10.3. Shortly below that part, it says: “Mac OS versions 8.1 through 10.2.x used decompositions based on Unicode 2.1. Mac OS X version 10.3 and later use decompositions based on Unicode 3.2.” So arguably the right encoding base was `kTextEncodingUnicodeV2_1`, and is now `kTextEncodingUnicodeV3_2` (at least for volumes last mounted writable on post-10.3 systems).

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for `-[NSString fileSystemRepresentation]` method.

Note that there is no general solution for this task. What is a valid file name depends on filesystem of the volume you're saving on. Not every file name valid for HFS+ is valid for FAT32, for example.

For Mac's “standard” filesystem (currently HFS+), `fileSystemRepresentation` should give what you need; for other file systems, there is no general way. Think about ones that don't exist but will be introduced in the future, for example :)

Answer (score 1):

According to your link, filesystem drivers appear to (mostly) follow one of two behaviours:
* Return all names in NFD, and convert names as appropriate.
* Don't perform any conversions.

In both these cases, if you create a file on OSX in NFD, reading it back on OSX should give you the name in NFD.

OTOH, if your filename goes from Windows → NFS → Mac and you want to do some sort of sync, you're out of luck. This is not an easy thing to do, since the underlying problem is a little philosophical: Should filenames be byte strings or Unicode strings? I believe Unix traditionally does the former, and at least in Linux, UTF-8 NFC names are merely a *convention*.

(It gets worse, since IIRC HFS+ is defined to use Unicode 3.something, so a naïve conversion to NFD might be wrong for characters added/changed since then unless the API you use can guarantee a specific Unicode version.)